# how to decode ASP.NET in JAVA

Tags: java, asp.net, .net, decode, encode

I need some help to determine which decode function to use in order to ger the original string,
encoded string is:

> {C3CFB141-79CE-4D8D-B81E-E8D0DC023B04}

decoded string is:

> 4131074

ASP.NET is the programing language used to encode the string, I need to decode it on JAVA

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't look encoded, but only some sort of unique identifier.

Comment: well, still any idea what the connection between them?

Comment: hexafraction is almost certainly correct, and to follow on, you probably won't be able to "decode" that UUID into that string. It's likely a mapping maintained on the server you're querying.